# How can I transpose multiple rows into a column with multiple matched outcomes?

Tags: google-sheets

I have this data set:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ilTZ.jpg]

and I want to transpose it where the Date is in a Column then A is in the next Column and B on the next

I used this formula 
`= Transpose(Index($B$1:$D$11,match(F$1,$A$1:$A$11,0)))` but the outcome gives only the first table

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHHEq.jpg]

What can I do to make my data look like this?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIrjE.jpg]

(so that whenever I would add a new week's data, my table would also change).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be possible with some ingenious queries, but to me it seemed easier to write a script (entered via *Tools > Script editor*). It updates the sheet as new data is entered. Some explanation:

- The output is set to begin at cell F1, as in your example. This can be changed by changing the row number and column number `1, 6` near the end of the script.
- The number of desired columns, `newColumns`, is inferred by going through column A until there is an empty cell in it. In your case, A4 is the first empty cell, which signifies you have 3 rows of data, so there will be 3 columns.
- The script assumes there is an empty column to the right of the input, which serves as an indication that the input ends there.

The logic is pretty straightforward: grabbing and pushing data around.

```
function onEdit() {
  var i,j,k; 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var v = range.getValues();
  i = 0;
  while (v[i][0]) {i++;}
  var newColumns = i;
  var row = [];
  for (k=0; k<newColumns; k++) {
    row.push(v[k][0]);
  }
  var values = [row];
  for (i=0; i<v.length-newColumns+1; i++) {
    if (v[i][0] == 'Date') {
      for (j=1; j<v[i].length; j++) {
        if (!v[i][j]) {break;}
        row = [];
        for (k=0; k<newColumns; k++) {
          row.push(v[i+k][j]);
        }
        values.push(row);
      }
    }  
  }
  var newRange = sheet.getRange(1, 6, values.length, newColumns);
  newRange.setValues(values);
}
```

If you want to put the output on another sheet, replace the command

```
 var newRange = sheet.getRange(1, 6, values.length, newColumns);
```

with

```
 var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Your target sheet name'); 
 var newRange = targetSheet.getRange(1, 6, values.length, newColumns);
```

(You may also want to change 1, 6 to something else like 1, 1 now that the output   has its own sheet.)